# How to cache a lazy load table without external library

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a table that I'm currently lazy loading, and I want to cache the data of the 5 most current pages. When a user clicks the forward or backward button, I will send the **pageNumber** that they are going to, and the direction they are going(**prev** or **next**).

In my getData function, I will check if the page they are going to exists in a **cachedData** array or not. If yes, then I will dispatch that data without making an api call. If no, I will see the direction they are going to. For example, if they are going 1 -> 5, then page 6, I will remove page 1 from the **cachedData** array, then push page 6 in, and if they are going backward 6 -> 1, I will remove page 6, cuz it's the farthest from current page, and push page 1 instead. Below are the implementations:

```js
const cachedData = [];
async function getData({ payload }) {
  const { pageNumber, ...currentPageInfo } = payload;
  const cachedPage = cachedData.find(page => page.pageNumber === pageNumber);
  if (!cachedPage) {
    const response = await fetchData(currentPageInfo);
    if (response) {
      if (cachedData.length >= 5) {
        if (currentPageInfo.direction === "next") cachedData.shift();
        cachedData.pop();
      }
      const { pageInfo, dataList } = response.data;
      cachedData.push({
        dataList,
        pageNumber,
        pageInfo,
      });
      cachedData.sort((x, y) => x.pageNumber - y.pageNumber);
      dispatch(getDataSuccess({ res: dataList, pageInfo }));
    }
  } else {
    dispatch(
      getDataSuccess({
        res: cachedPage.dataList,
        pageInfo: cachedPage.pageInfo,
      })
    );
  }
}
```

Currently it's working, but I'm not sure I'm on the right track. Between the shifting, sorting and finding, the performance aren't very good. The logic is weird because we are using our own way of pagination, and not the usual **skip** and **take** approach. But the important thing is whether anything can be improved in this code. Thank you very much.

Comment: have you looked at any performance metrics?  how have you determined that performance is not very good?

Comment: no it's my personal opinion only, cuz it takes 1 second or 2 for cachedData to show up on the UI, and I don't think things like sort and shift are very performant.